# Sharepoint 2010 start workflow programmatically error

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I have a workflow associated with a content type.  I try to kick it off from code from within the event receiver on the same content type, so when an item is updated, if there is a certain condition (status = ready for review) I start it.

//This line does find the workflow association

```
var assoc = properties.Web.ContentTypes["Experiment Document Set"]
         .WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName("Experiment Review Workflow",
          ultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
```

//I had tried to use this line from something I found online, but it would return null

```
assoc = properties.Web.WorkflowAssociations
     .GetAssociationByName("Experiment Review Workflow",
      CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
```

The next line gives an error:

```
var result = properties.Web.Site.WorkflowManager
                       .StartWorkflow(properties.ListItem, assoc,string.Empty,
                                      SPWorkflowRunOptions.Synchronous);
```

> System.ArgumentException: Workflow failed to start because the workflow is associated with a content type that does not exist in a list.  Before re-starting the workflow, the content type must be added to the list.

To check this, I was looking at the content type of the list item being updated and it is correct

```
properties.ListItem.ContentType.Name    "Experiment Document Set"
```

So basically I have a workfow associated with the content type "Experiment Document Set".  When I try to start a workflow from an event receiver in "Experiment Document Set", I get an error saying the content type "Experiment Document Set" does not exist in the list which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure assoc.Enabled = true.

Answer (score -1):

Probably too late to be helpful, but I just learned that you can't use `String.Empty` (or `null`) in the `StartWorkflow` method.

From http://www.tonytestasworld.com/post/Howto-Start-a-Sharepoint-Workflow-Programmatically.aspx, it looks like `assoc.AssociationData` would work for a simple workflow without any configuration parameters.

I can't test this (yet), because I'm stuck a step earlier, possibly similar to the issue you mentioned in your first two code examples.